# MS Build publishing SSDT project errors creating SQL Server Logins

Tags: sql-server, msbuild, jenkins, sql-server-data-tools

I have been automating database deployment using SQL Server Data Tools, ms build and Jenkins. I am using a dummy publish profile

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <IncludeCompositeObjects>True</IncludeCompositeObjects>
    <TargetDatabaseName>AdventureWorksDW</TargetDatabaseName>
    <DeployScriptFileName>AdventureWorksDW.sql</DeployScriptFileName>
    <TargetConnectionString>Data Source=.;Integrated     Security=True;Pooling=False</TargetConnectionString>
    <BlockWhenDriftDetected>False</BlockWhenDriftDetected>
    <RegisterDataTierApplication>False</RegisterDataTierApplication>
    <BlockOnPossibleDataLoss>True</BlockOnPossibleDataLoss>
    <IgnorePermissions>True</IgnorePermissions>
    <CreateNewDatabase>True</CreateNewDatabase>
    <ProfileVersionNumber>1</ProfileVersionNumber>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

I am then overriding certain values within this using the property switch with ms build.

Despite not including permissions in the project and setting IgnorePermisssions to true I get the following output from ms build.

```
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 4.0.30319.17929
[Microsoft .NET Framework, version 4.0.30319.17929]
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Build started 05/09/2012 17:35:28.
Project "E:\Jenkins\workspace\Publish SSDT with parameters\Database\ETL POC\AdventureWorksDW\AdventureWorksDW.sqlproj" on node 1 (Publish target(s)).
SqlPublish:
  Deployment script generated to:
  E:\Jenkins\workspace\Publish SSDT with parameters\Database\ETL POC\AdventureWorksDW\bin\Debug\AdventureWorksDW.publish.sql

  Creating AdventureWorksDW...
  Creating [My-Domain\jenkins]...
E:\Jenkins\workspace\Publish SSDT with parameters\Database\ETL POC\AdventureWorksDW\bin\Debug\AdventureWorksDW.publish.sql(173,1,173,1): Deploy error SQL72014: .Net SqlClient Data Provider: Msg 15063, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 The login already has an account under a different user name. [E:\Jenkins\workspace\Publish SSDT with parameters\Database\ETL POC\AdventureWorksDW\AdventureWorksDW.sqlproj]
  An error occurred while the batch was being executed.
Done Building Project "E:\Jenkins\workspace\Publish SSDT with parameters\Database\ETL POC\AdventureWorksDW\AdventureWorksDW.sqlproj" (Publish target(s)) -- FAILED.

Build FAILED.
```

EDIT:

I have now archived the publish script from msbuild. The section below has been edited to excluded irrelevant database options being set and ends at the command which raises the error.

```
/*
Deployment script for AdventureWorksDW

This code was generated by a tool.
Changes to this file may cause incorrect behavior and will be lost if
the code is regenerated.
*/
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS, ANSI_PADDING, ANSI_WARNINGS, ARITHABORT, CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL, QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON;

SET NUMERIC_ROUNDABORT OFF;
GO

:setvar DatabaseName "AdventureWorksDW"
:setvar DefaultFilePrefix "AdventureWorksDW"
:setvar DefaultDataPath "E:\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\"
:setvar DefaultLogPath "E:\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\"
GO

:on error exit
GO

/*
Detect SQLCMD mode and disable script execution if SQLCMD mode is not supported.
To re-enable the script after enabling SQLCMD mode, execute the following:
SET NOEXEC OFF; 
*/
:setvar __IsSqlCmdEnabled "True"
GO
IF N'$(__IsSqlCmdEnabled)' NOT LIKE N'True'
    BEGIN
        PRINT N'SQLCMD mode must be enabled to successfully execute this script.';
        SET NOEXEC ON;
    END


GO
USE [master];
GO

IF (DB_ID(N'$(DatabaseName)') IS NOT NULL) 
BEGIN
    ALTER DATABASE [$(DatabaseName)]
    SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;
    DROP DATABASE [$(DatabaseName)];
END

GO
PRINT N'Creating $(DatabaseName)...'
GO
CREATE DATABASE [$(DatabaseName)]
    ON 
    PRIMARY(NAME = [$(DatabaseName)], FILENAME = N'$(DefaultDataPath)$(DefaultFilePrefix)_Primary.mdf')
    LOG ON (NAME = [$(DatabaseName)_log], FILENAME = N'$(DefaultLogPath)$(DefaultFilePrefix)_Primary.ldf') COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS
GO
GO
PRINT N'Creating [MY-DOMAIN\jenkins]...';

GO
CREATE USER [MY-DOMAIN\jenkins] FOR LOGIN [DR-FOSTER\jenkins];
```

I have ran this script outside of Jenkins and it succeeds but that is under a different used account.

It seems as though despite MY-DOMAIN\jenkins creating the database and therefore being the owner the publish script wants to then create a user and set that as db_owner.

Does any one have any experience doing similar? This is starting to feel like a bug.

Thanks

Comment: Updated to include publish script.

Comment: Do I understand correctly: the script there is the one generated by SSDT, and you have a user specified in the database which you're asking SSDT to create, but that user is the same user that's executing the build?  (I just realized how old this question is, feel free to just take this as a reminder to answer yourself and get points if you've already figured this out).

Answer (score 2):

I have seen that SQL Server error before when trying to add a windows user to a database, when the user was already in the dbowner role.  Changing the dbowner to something like sa allows you to add the user to the database.

It would help to share the actual SQL statements that are being processed.

Comment: Thanks for that, it is indeed trying to create an account despite being the owner. I have added the publish script which confirms this. Question is why is the script being generated in this way.